# why %*c not working in the expression "%[^\n]s%*c"

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

Here is the code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct driverDetail
{
    char name[20];
    int licenseNumber;
    char route[20];
    int kms;
};

int main()
{
    struct driverDetail drivers[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter details for driver %d :\n", i+1);
        printf("Enter driver's name : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s%*c", &drivers[i].name);
        printf("Enter driver's license number : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]d%*c", &drivers[i].licenseNumber);
        printf("Enter driver's route : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s%*c", &drivers[i].route);
        printf("Enter driver's kilometers driven : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]d%*c", &drivers[i].kms);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        printf("driver %d name : %s\n", i+1, drivers[i].name);
        printf("driver %d license number : %d\n", i+1, drivers[i].licenseNumber);
        printf("driver %d route : %s\n", i+1, drivers[i].route);
        printf("driver %d kilometers driven : %d\n", i+1, drivers[i].kms);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`%[^\n]%*c` works completely fine but why `%[^\n]s%*c` is not working.

when I use `%[^\n]%*c` **\n** gets rejected by the first format specifier and then %*c read the **\n** and discards it. But why **%*c** is not discarding **\n** when used with `%[^\n]s%*c`.

Same case with **%d**, **%*c** works with `%d%*c` but not with `%[^\n]d%*c`.

Why is this happening ? can somebody explain.

Comment: What do you enter as input? What is the purpose of the extra `s`? You seem to assume that `[^\n]` would be related to `%s` or `%d` which is not the case.

Comment: Instead of trying to get rid of the newline that ended the scan with `%*c`, place a space in front of `"%[^\n]"` like `" %[^\n]"`. That is how `scanf` is intended to be used. If you find yourself kludging newlines with `scanf` your are either using it incorrectly, or using the wrong function entirely (consider using `fgets` and `sscanf`).

Comment: @WeatherVane adding space before the formate working, but can you explain to me how it works.

Comment: Most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too. By design, `scanf` is *intended* to work that way. It reads up to the character it cannot convert, and that remains in the buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane `scanf` filters leading whitespace and read the rest and convert it, but the rest contains `\n` at the end,so how adding leading whitespace removes the `\n` at the end

Comment: It removes the whitespace left in the input from the *previous* input. The newline at the end of *this* input remains in the buffer, which will be read by the *next* `scanf` call. You don't normally need to remove trailing whitespace (except when using `fgets` which has different behaviour and should not be mixed with `scanf`).

Comment: If it will read by the next `scanf` wouldn't it work like pressing enter in the input.

Comment: As I wrote, the newline will be filtered with most format specs, such as `%d` `%s` `%f` but will be read by `%c` and `%[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When scanf reads input according to one of the formats `%[^\n]s%*c` and `%[^\n]d%*c`, and the behavior is well defined (*i.e.* the object receiving the data corresponding to the `%[` directive is not overrun), there must be either an input failure or a matching failure at the `s` or `d`.  This is because `scanf` will expect each of these to match a literal character (a literal 's' or 'd'), but if there are any more characters available then the next one must be a newline.  Anything else will have been consumed by the `%[`.

Perhaps you meant `%[^\n]%d`, `%[^\n]%*s`, or similar.  The `%s` and `%d` directives skip leading whitespace, including newlines (unlike `%c` or `%*c`), so they would attempt to read past the newline (if any) up next in the input.

Note also that all of these alternatives afford the possibility of an *input failure*, as I already mentioned.  That is, if the `%[` consumes all the bytes up to the end of the stream, such that there are none left to read, then `scanf` quits.  Its return value will reflect that.  Take care, however, not to confuse "end of stream" with the temporary absence of characters to read.  These are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate in detail on how will the scanf process the input w.r.t to these %[^\n]%d, %[^\n]%*s

Comment: @HarshitSingh, if you have a followup question then please pose it as its own question.  However, I urge you to read `scanf`'s documentation for details on how it operates, and to reserve your questions for matters that the documentation does not answer for you, or where you don't understand the documentation.

Comment: Can you pls share the link for the documentation? I myself have been finding one.

Comment: if using linux, then on the command line type:  `man scanf`

Comment: if accessing the internet, then with in your web browser search field enter something similar to `syntax for scanf in c`